# GCP Dataproc - adding multiple packages(kafka, mongodb) while submitting jobs not working

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, dependency-management, spark-structured-streaming, dataproc

I'm trying to add the kafka & mongoDB packages while submitting dataproc pyspark jobs, however that is failing.
So far, i've been using only kafka package and that is working fine,
however when i try to add mongoDB package in the command below it gives error

Command working fine, with only Kafka package

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark main.py \
  --cluster versa-structured-stream  \
  --properties spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2, spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true,spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
```

I tried e few options to add both the packages, however that is not working :
eg.

```
--properties ^#^spark:spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2,spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true,spark:spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true,spark:spark.executor.memory=20g,spark:spark.driver.memory=5g,spark:spark.executor.cores=2 \
  --jars=gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-avro_2.12-3.1.2.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/isolation-forest_2.4.3_2.12-2.0.8.jar,gs://dataproc-spark-jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.23.2.jar \
  --region us-east1 \
  --py-files streams.zip,utils.zip


Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1abcccefa3144660967606f3f7f9491d/main.py", line 303, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/1abcccefa3144660967606f3f7f9491d/main.py", line 260, in main
    df_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 482, in load
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
```

How do i make this work ?

tia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `--properties` you have defined `^#^` as delimiter. To properly use the delimiter you need to change the `,` to `#` as separator of your properties. You will only use `,` when defining multiple values in a single key. Also you need to remove `spark:` prefix on your properties. See sample command below:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark main.py \
  --cluster=cluster-3069  \
  --region=us-central1 \
  --properties ^#^spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2#spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true#spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true#spark.executor.memory=20g#spark.driver.memory=5g#spark.executor.cores=2
```

When job config is inspected this is the result:

[image]